# Combining pandas dataframes and ArcGIS feature classes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, arcpy

I have a bit of a general question about the compatibility of Pandas dataframes and Arc featureclasses.

My current project is within ArcGIS and so I am mapping mostly with featureclasses. I am however, most familiar with using pandas to perform simple data analysis with tables. Therefore, I am attempting to work with dataframes for the most part, and then join their data to feature classes for final mapping using some key field common between sets.

**Attempts:**

1.I have come to find that arcpy AddJoin does not accept dfs.

2.I am currently trying convert df to csv and then do an Addjoin however I am unsure if this is supported and I far prefer the functionality of filtering dfs with "df.loc" etc.

3. Update cursor seems to be a good option, however, I am experiencing issues accessing the key field of the "row" in my loop to match records. I will post another  question about this as it is a separate issue.

Which of these or other options is the best for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Esri introduced something called [Spatially Enabled DataFrame](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/):

> The Spatially Enabled DataFrame inserts a custom namespace called spatial into the popular Pandas DataFrame structure to give it spatial abilities. This allows you to use intutive, pandorable operations on both the attribute and spatial columns.

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

# important as it "enhances" Pandas by importing these classes
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor
```

```py
# from a shape file
df = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass(r"data\hospitals.shp")
```

```py
# from a map layer
project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
map = project.activeMap
first_layer = map.listLayers()[0]
layer_name = first_layer.name

df = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass(layer_name)

# or directly by name
df = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass("Streets")

# of if nested within a group layer (e.g. Buildings)
df = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass("Buildings\Residential")
```

```py
# save to shapefile
df.spatial.to_featureclass(location=r"c:\temp\residential_buildings.shp")
```

However, you have to use intermediate files if you go back and forth (to my knowledge). Although it's a bit tricky having [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) installed along `arcpy`, it may be worth looking into (only) using `geopandas`.

IMHO, I would recommend that you avoid unnecessarily going back and forth between `arcpy` and `pandas`. Pandas allows to [merge, join and concat](https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/) dataframes. Or, you may be able to do everything in `geopandas` without needing to touch `arcpy` functions at all.

Comment: Thanks for offering a clearer picture of spatially enabled dataframes to me! I am going to put this to the test and see how it turns out. As long as I can go back and forth once then I dont think there should be a problem, but we shall see.